# Каким образом связать Telegram бота с программой 1C

Tags: python, 1с

возникла проблема, каким образом связать Telegram бота и программу 1C.
Пример:
Через 1С человек сделал какой-то заказа и нужно чтобы бот отправил об этом уведомление в чат телеграма, возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Вполне возможно.

Comment: полагаю у 1с есть вебхуки, бота к ним подвязать

Comment: Понял, я а как?

Comment: https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/1737654/

Answer (score 1):

[Пишем TELEGRAM бота на 1С. С нуля и до ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peZsik57m4k)

https://geopressa.ru/stati/integratsiya-1s-i-telegram

https://nizamov.school/courses/integration1s/telegram1s/

https://rps-1c.ru/content/published/1ccrm/telegrammUNF/

https://docs.telefon1c.ru/user-guides/telegram/podkluchenie/